# Perform functions using Column Number (Not Column Name)

Tags: r

I have a DataFrame **"Software"** and I need to perform functions on its ***Columns Number*** not using column name. e.g.

```
Software <- aggregate(Software$`Amount1`, by=list(Tower_Name=Software$`Tower`), FUN=sum)
```

Here, the column name **"Amount1"** varies and I need to use its Number[7] to be used in a loop.
**What I need is** flexible way to deal with columns' name, and I thought of column Number here.

Comment: May be you need to use the `formula` method `aggregate(.~ Tower, Software[c(7, match('Tower', names(Software)))], FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to subset the data by the column number and then use the `formula` method of `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ cbind(Tower_Name = Tower), 
       Software[c(7, match('Tower', names(Software)))], FUN = sum)
```

The key is the column subset of 'Software'.  Here, we already know the column index of 'Amount' as 7, concatenate with the matching index of 'Tower' column outputs a two column dataframe.  In the formula method, we can specify `.` to all other columns.  Here, it would be 'Amount' or variations of its name

---

With `tidyverse`, this would be more easier, as there are `summarise_at` that can take either column names or index

```
library(tidyverse)
Software %>%
     group_by(Tower) %>%
     summarise_at(7, sum)
```

Comment: I had thought as `names(Software)[7] <- "Amount"` and then using this name for all purpose. But this would have been an inefficient method!